# "Invalid value constant value "for TextEditingController in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Was building UI with TextField() in Flutter, I defined the controller in state and tried to use that defined emailController and passwordController in TextField() but it says "Invalid constant value.". I tried to resolve it but didn't work. Here is the code for login_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rider_app/routes/routing_constants.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _validate = false;
  
  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   emailController.dispose();
  //   passwordController.dispose();
  //   super.dispose();
  // }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
            ),
            const Center(
                child: Image(
              image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/logo.png"),
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            )),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 2.0,
            ),
            const Text(
              "Login as a Rider",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: "Brand Bold"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  const TextField(
                    
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Email",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      hintText: "Email address",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey),
                      // focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      //   borderSide:
                      //       BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      // ),
                      // enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      //   borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0),
                      // ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                    controller: emailController,
                    
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  const TextField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Password",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                      hintText: "Your password",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey),
                      // focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      //   borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                    // enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    //   borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0)
                    // )
                    // ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 45.0,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      debugPrint("Logged In");
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, homeScreen);
                    },
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 23, vertical: 11),
                      child: Text(
                        'Login',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: "Brand Bold",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, signUpScreen);
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      "Don't have Account?",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontFamily: "Brand-Regular"),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      " Register Here.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Brand-Regular",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    )
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The controller defination is okay but as I try to assign controller to the `TextField()` controller, the error is thrown. Screenshot attached herewith:

[image]

Have any idea ?? let me know, even suggetion is appreciated. Thank you!

GitHub Repo: [Project Link Github](https://github.com/PremDS/uber_clone)

Comment: change `const TextField` to `TextField`. It's because `controller` is not a constant.

Comment: The habit of placing const whenever Text Editor shows warning. Anyway thanks mate.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Remove the `const` before TextField, that should resolve the error.

Comment: The habit of placing const whenever Text Editor shows warning. Anyway thanks mate.

Comment: no problem and btw which theme are you using, it looks really good.

Comment: It's material theme mate.

Answer (score 7):

remove `const` from `const TextField` and you are good to go.

Your code will be like this:

```
           TextField( 
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Email",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Remove const keywords at the beginning of TextField widgets.

Comment: The habit of placing const whenever Text Editor shows warning. Anyway thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `const` modifier from the `TextField`.

Comment: The habit of placing const whenever Text Editor shows warning. Anyway thanks mate.

Comment: Yeah I know, that yellow underlined warning is so hard to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the "const" before TextField, (or one of the top widgets in the widget tree), that should resolve the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try by removing const before Expanded, it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the 'const' to be removed is not the one preceding the TextField widget, but the one preceding its (TextField) parent widget.